# Fatal error sqlsrv_connect()

Tags: php, sql-server-2008-r2, xampp

I want to connect to a MSSQL 2008 database using PHP. Below is the code I am trying to use

```
<?php

$serverName = "psherathpc"; //serverName\instance
$connectionInfo = array("Database">"shoe_shop", "UID"=>"psherathpc\psherath", "PWD"=>"" );

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if($conn)
{
    echo "Connection established.<br/>";
}
else
{
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br/>";
    die( print_r( sqlsvr_error(), true));
}

?>
```

I am receiving the error `Fatal error sqlsrv_connect()`. How can I solve this problem? Please tell me step-by-step clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You should always state exactly what error you are receiving but..

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($severName, $connectionInfo);
```

you mispelled $serverName. This possibly could be one solution.